# Is their any way to set the Media Projection Permission to Entire screen option by Default in Android 14 (Beta 3.1)?

Tags: mobile-development, android-mediaprojection

I have an app which has the feature of casting the screen using the Media Projection API in android

With the recently released beta (3.1) for Android 14 the user has to select the option to cast a single app or the full screen.

**Single App**

With this option the user is able to select the app which they want to share the screen with others. This option allows the media projection to be stopped when the app is killed

**Entire screen**

This casts the entire phone's screen without any restriction

---

Is there any way to set the option to the entire screen by default?

So far i have tried to find which option the user selected by using the Media Projection manager in my code, but still can't find any solutions so I'm stuck on this

so please share your answers it will be helpfull for all . thanks in advance

Note : This feature is released in *Android 14 Beta 3.1 program*. so far the listed device from google can get this feature update if they join the beta

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArSRC.png)

Comment: yes it is related programming @DarkBee

Comment: okay will edit my question now @DarkBee

Comment: i have edited my question may i know my you have  down voted @DarkBee

Comment: For example : I have a app which has feature of  cast the screen using Media Projection Api in android . Now in android 14 beta 3.1 program their is a new update which holds two option which i have above mentioned . for this case i need to  set the option to entire screen by default .

pls note : still feature not released in stable currently in beta usage . for this  i have tried  some steps which i can't get any fixes . i think i am clear at my point .

this is what i have explained above

Comment: "*has feature of cast the screen using Media Projection Api*" - Why don't you add your *current* code into the question then?

Comment: the feature has a new update in Android 14 beta  so how come my old code will help ?  . then most android developers know about media projection . then  in this case problem  is  not in  my code . i am asking for some other solution from others devlopers who may have some other ideas to set the option by default

Comment: Because chances are the "old" code might require some tweaking, .e.g. passing other parameters or using another method and it makes this question more useful and it actually shows this is programming related

Comment: agree with our point !!. but this is question finding the loophole  in android . so the code might not help full and my  i have implemented media projection as per developer document recently so no deperected code are their

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app compileSdk version 34? If it is, you can use [MediaProjectionConfig](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionConfig) when calling createScreenCaptureIntent from media projection manager object.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
        screenRecorderServiceLauncher.launch(
            mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(MediaProjectionConfig.createConfigForDefaultDisplay())
        )
    } else {
        screenRecorderServiceLauncher.launch(
            mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()
        )
    }
```

The createConfigForDefaultDisplay() defines the screen recorder to only allow user to use as "entire screen" when using a media projection service from your application.

Comment: this method worked  for in 6 but not working in 7A  am i need to modify any thing ?